# Groovy : Find the date of the previous Monday

Tags: date, groovy

In the following code, i want to find the date of the last Monday.
For that, i have two variable :

- startDay = today - 7 days
- stopDay = today - 1 day (yesterday)

And i have a function that list all dates between "startDay" and "stopDay", and search in these dates, which one corresponds to Monday.

It works well when i have two dates in the same ten :

- startDay = 2014-07-20
- stopDay = 2014-07-29

But, when one of both change decade, the code end with an error:

- startDay = 2014-07-29
- stopDay = 2014-07-30

ERROR:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incompatible Strings for Range: String#next() will not reach the expected value**

**CODE:**

```
def searchDay = { start, stop -> (start..stop).findAll { Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "${it}").format("u") == "1" } }
def startDay = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()-7)
def stopDay = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()-1)

def dateOfTheDay = searchDay(startDay, stopDay);
def dateOfTheDayWithoutSquare = dateOfTheDay.join(", ")


return dateOfTheDayWithoutSquare
```

Comment: use joda, and be done with it: ``@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.4')
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants
println LocalDate.now().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)
``

Comment: Thanks @cfrick, i didn't know Joda/Joda-time, but it seems to be easiest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will find the previous Monday starting from today

```
def cal = Calendar.instance

while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1)
}

Date lastMonday = cal.time

// print the date in yyyy-MM-dd format
println lastMonday.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

If you want to find the Monday previous to some other date replace the first line with:

```
def cal = Calendar.instance
Date someOtherDate = // get a date from somewhere
cal.time = someOtherDate
```

Comment: Dónal, thanks to your answer! it works but if you can tell me how can i format it to ("yyyy-MM-dd") format? (i'm new in coding! using this to my webservices' tests).
i tried : Date lastMonday = cal.time.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
but finish with this error:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '2014-07-26' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'

Answer (score 5):

This should be a touch faster (no loop):

```
def cal = Calendar.instance
def diff = Calendar.MONDAY - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, diff)
cal.time.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: for me this was giving a future date, tested with current date as 09/05/2021 and wanted last saturday, but i got 15/05/2021